# Union results of two completely separate searches

Tags: elasticsearch

My client wants to be able to perform a search, see the results, and then perform another completely unrelated search, and have the new results appended to the previous results.

I'm trying to find a way to do this within ElasticSearch, so that I can still use the built-in pagination.

The complication here is that each search may have multiple query parts that will be combined independently of other searches. So for example, I may do one search that looks for any ACTIVE properties with the keyword "123 Anywhere St." and a price range of 100000 to 150000. That search will look like this:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 25,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "statusId": [
            1,
            2
          ]
        }
      },
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "123 Anywhere St.",
            "fuzziness": 0,
            "prefix_length": 0,
            "fields": [
              "searchable_name^10",
              "searchable_mapAddress",
              "searchable_streetName2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": 100000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "lte": 150000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And then, I may do another completely different search that uses the keyword "234 Elsewhere St." and search on a size range instead of price, and looks for a different status.

I want all of the results from the first search to show up, and then all of the results from the second search to show up, in a single paginated result set.

Can this be done in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search). All you need to do is provide the search requests to the **_msearch** endpoint.

```
GET index_name/_msearch
{}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
{}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
```

Hope it helps !